# Pulling upstream banches into fork

Tags: git, github, branch

I'm having issues getting some of the new branches created on the original repository into my fork. I attempted to follow the commands found from googling but have no luck, here's what I'm doing:

```
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/master

git fetch origin
get checkout -b n3690 remotes/origin/n3690
```

which gives me the error

> Fatal: cannot update path and switch to branch 'n3690' at the same
>   time. Did you intend to checkout 'remotes/origin/n3690' which can not
>   be resolved as commit?

The branch still does not appear on my fork which confuses me, how can I get the branches to update to my fork? If my question is not clear enough, I want to update my fork [here](https://github.com/Syntaf/hpx) so it includes all of the branches that the [main repository](https://github.com/STEllAR-GROUP/hpx) has.

Comment: FYI, I just tried `git checkout -b <branch> remotes/origin/<branch>`, and that worked. I'm also using Git version 1.9.2 though. What version of Git are you using?

Comment: @Cupcake I may or may not have been trying to check out `3690` instead of `3960`  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `git checkout -b n3690 origin/n3690`.

This is possible assuming that you have a branch called `n3690` on the remote called `origin`. This in turn means that you have a remote called `origin`. You can confirm that by running a `git remote -v` and checking if `origin` is present in the list. As a single check you can do a `git branch -r`, that shows the list of remote branches and see if the branch `origin/n3690` is present in the list.

Comment: FYI, I just tried `git checkout -b <branch> remotes/origin/<branch>` like the original poster did, and it worked. So it shouldn't have mattered that he used `remotes/origin/<branch>` instead of `origin/<branch>`.

Answer (score 2):

In newer versions of git you can just do this:

```
git checkout n3690
```

Read more about it here http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout:

> ```
> git checkout <branch>
> ```
>
> If `<branch>` is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it `<remote>`) with a matching name,
>   treat as equivalent to
>
> `$ git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>`